# Taking "Absolute Value Operator" as a common factor?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

If I have an equation like this and Im trying to solve for X

```
|x| + 4|x| = 40
```

Can I take the absolute Value (Modulus) as a common factor?

```
|x + 4x| = 40
```

and the proceed to solve for X?

Comment: You can only write $|a|+|b|=|a+b|$ if you know that $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.  In this case, you do know that $x$ and $4x$ have the same sign, so it's okay… but here there is a more straightforward method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general $|a|+|b|\ne|a+b|$

See [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml), for the general relation

We can write $$|x|(1+4)=40\implies 5|x|=40$$

Things become more clear if we substitute $|x|$ with $y$